# Having trouble sending client certificate in libcurl ssl request, what am I missing?

Tags: c++, ssl, libcurl

I'm trying to send a client certificate to a webserver that requires it.

If I make the request from the command line curl command, it works.
I pass  --key filename and --cert filename and everything works fine.

When I do it from the libcurl library, I do this:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, client_cert_file.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, client_key_file.c_str());
```

Same exact thing, the server says the client certificate is missing.

I tried doing things like giving it a nonexistent filename in hopes of provoking some other error messages that might give me a clue what's wrong, but libcurl (and command line curl for that matter)  with verbose on don't yield any error messages when something goes wrong. Surely there's a failure case, but nothing is yielding me any kind of error to follow up on.

Is there any way to get more diagnostics out of libcurl?

Pulling what's left of my hair out here.

This is on windows 10 by the way, we built libcurl ourselves. SSL is built in, https connections work, I just can't get it to send the client cert and there's no indication what's going wrong.

UPDATE:

I think I found my problem...

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#Add_support_for_client_certifica

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

Okay so I worked something out.

It turns out you can build libcurl on windows with openssh or schannel.
If you use schannel, then the  CURLOPT_SSLCERT and  CURLOPT_SSLKEY do nothing. (no warning or error mind you.)
Maybe they do do something, in relation to schannel, but I couldn't find any docs on that.

So in short if you build libcurl with openssl you can supply a client cert to send in the TLS handshake.

The tipoff was here:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#Add_support_for_client_certifica

Comment: This functionality was added in curl 7.60 released on May 16th, 2018 (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 0):

Support for CURLOPT_SSLCERT in conjunction with WinSSL/SChannel was added in curl 7.60.0 ([changelog](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html)).

As the [documentation for CURLOPT_SSLCERT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT.html) states:

> Client certificates must be specified by a path expression to a certificate store. [...] You can use "<store location>\<store name>\<thumbprint>" to refer to a certificate in the system certificates store, for example, "CurrentUser\MY\934a7ac6f8a5d579285a74fa61e19f23ddfe8d7a". [...] Following store locations are supported: CurrentUser, LocalMachine, CurrentService, Services, CurrentUserGroupPolicy, LocalMachineGroupPolicy, LocalMachineEnterprise.

Comment: yeah, but what I was looking for was a way to use the old style point-to-a-cert-file mechanism. it took me a while to realize that wasn't possible when compiled this way.