# Using libcurl from C++/Windows to post to an API that requires a client certificate for authentication? Getting CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libcurl

I have searched here, but did not find anything that matched. What I have tested with curl.exe and that works fine. I then tried a small test program. Created a commandline Win32 project in VS2017 and copied in the code from simplessl.c. Problem is that no matter what certificates I try I always get CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM. This points to the client certificate being wrong. I even tried with the 2048 bit certificate and key from here: https://fm4dd.com/openssl/certexamples.shtm Not sure how to troubleshoot.

The test program I used:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE *headerfile;
    const char *pPassphrase = NULL;

    static const char *pCertFile = "C:\\Prog\\TestCurl\\2048b-rsa-example-cert.pem";
    static const char *pCACertFile = "cacert.pem";
    static const char *pHeaderFile = "C:\\Prog\\TestCurl\\requestWith.txt";

    const char *pKeyName;
    const char *pKeyType;

    const char *pEngine;

#ifdef USE_ENGINE
    pKeyName = "rsa_test";
    pKeyType = "ENG";
    pEngine = "chil";            /* for nChiper HSM... */
#else
    pKeyName = "C:\\Prog\\TestCurl\\2048b-rsa-example-keypair.pem";
    pKeyType = "PEM";
    pEngine = NULL;
#endif

    headerfile = fopen(pHeaderFile, "wb");

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* what call to write: */
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pintatesti.vero.fi/FIS/Return/IIT/Test/GetWithholdingPercentage/v1");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.pedago.fi");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, headerfile);

        do { /* dummy loop, just to break out from */
            if (pEngine) {
                /* use crypto engine */
                if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLENGINE, pEngine) != CURLE_OK) {
                    /* load the crypto engine */
                    fprintf(stderr, "can't set crypto engine\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLENGINE_DEFAULT, 1L) != CURLE_OK) {
                    /* set the crypto engine as default */
                    /* only needed for the first time you load
                       a engine in a curl object... */
                    fprintf(stderr, "can't set crypto engine as default\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            /* cert is stored PEM coded in file... */
            /* since PEM is default, we needn't set it for PEM */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");

            /* set the cert for client authentication */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, pCertFile);

            /* sorry, for engine we must set the passphrase
               (if the key has one...) */
            if (pPassphrase)
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, pPassphrase);

            /* if we use a key stored in a crypto engine,
               we must set the key type to "ENG" */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, pKeyType);

            /* set the private key (file or ID in engine) */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, pKeyName);

            /* set the file with the certs vaildating the server */
            //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, pCACertFile);

            /* disconnect if we can't validate server's cert */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            /* Check for errors */
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

            /* we are done... */
        } while (0);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Underlying error I get is " schannel: certificate format compatibility error" and only occurrence I can find is in schannel.c where it compares to a P12 type, but my certs are PEM?

Edit2: So it does work if I import the certificate into the local store, something I would definitely want to avoid! Also curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); appears to be  avery good idea! Now getting further.

Edit3: Got it working. Possibly related to: [Having trouble sending client certificate in libcurl ssl request, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800527/having-trouble-sending-client-certificate-in-libcurl-ssl-request-what-am-i-miss) which is from 2019. I would very much prefer to have the certificates in a file though.

Edit4:  "libcurl/7.79.1 Schannel WinIDN"

Comment: What version of libcurl are you using?

Comment: libcurl_a_debug.lib from C:\Prog\curl-7.79.1\curl-7.79.1\builds\libcurl-vc-DESKTOP-0G0S0E1-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel\lib. So I assume it is 7.79. I added a curl_version() call and it returns "libcurl/7.79.1 Schannel WinIDN". Ie I downloaded the latest version and built it with "nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static DEBUG=yes"

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a little help from my friends. Libcurl when compiled as default on Windows will default to schannel. To override that you need to build for OpenSSL, thusly: `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static DEBUG=yes WITH_SSL=static WITH_DEVEL=C:\Prog\OpenSSL-Win32_111L\`. The important keywords are WITH_SSL=static or dynamic and WITH_DEVEL= path to where your OpenSSL files live. When built this way you can give file paths for certificate and key, ie: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, m_Certificate.GetString());`

This frees you of the messy certificate handling in Windows and lets you keep the certificates with the app itself.